# Keep at all times, the minus sign above aligned with minus sign below

Tags: macros, align, fractions

How can I change the frg command such that I can create and maintain at all times the minus sign above aligned with minus sign below?
PS: If you can show how to include a font setting for the whole macro, I'll consider it a good additional contribution to this answer.

[image: keep minus above align with minus below]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\minus}{\raisebox{.1in}{$-$ \ }}
\newcommand{\eq}{\textbf{\fontsize{45}{6}\selectfont\raisebox{-.16in}{\scalebox{.5}[1.1]{= \vspace{.03in}}}}}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\def\over{\abovewithdelims...32em}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\frg}[1]{%
  \frg@aux#1,,\@nil
}
\def\frg@aux#1,#2,#3\@nil{%
    \ensuremath{ \eq {{\raisebox{.069in}{ \ \centering \mbox{\fontsize{45}{6}\selectfont\textbf{#1}} \ }} 
    \over {\raisebox{-.275in}{ \ \centering\mbox{\fontsize{45}{6}\selectfont\textbf{#2}}}} \ }}
    } 
\makeatother

    \begin{document}
                \frg{4 \minus 3, \ 3 \minus 1  \ }
    \end{document}
```

Comment: These are not minus signs, but hyphen dashes. I don't see what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Comment: you don't give many hints of the intention of this construct, it looks like math but you are using text mode constructs, `\centering` is doing nothing in a `\raisebox` as that is set in horizontal mode, you have redefined `\over` so this will change `\frac` and `\buildrel` which are defined in terms of `\over.

Comment: your example uses single digits so everything aligns naturally, but does your question mean you want `\frac{123-1}{1-123}` with the `-` aligned?

Comment: Exactly @DavidCarlisle, I imagine it is a sufficient condition to keep the two minus signs aligned. As for mixing text mode with mathematical mode in addition to the likely inefficient use of \ centering is by lack of experience, I would be grateful for your answer to this my adding issue to the fixes and enhancements to fix what was unnecessary to use in my code so that I can learn.

Comment: I think marmot's answer does what you want. Not sure what else I could add.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know what the purpose of this exercise is but alignment can e.g. achieved with an array. Notice that I didn't pay any attention to spacing, bold and etc. because I do not know the purpose.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\frg@aux#1-#2,#3-#4\@nil{\begin{array}{@{\,}r@{}c@{}l@{\,}}
#1&-&#2\\
\hline
#3&-&#4
\end{array}}
\def\frg#1{\frg@aux#1\@nil}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[ a=\frg{4 - 3,  3 - 1  }\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Really @marmot, for academic use it is indifferent most often the alignment of operators within a fraction. But the need to specify the position of the operators in this case refers to the fate that I intend to give inside in the education of very small children in order to facilitate the visual reading. I have used very little array command, I have tried a few different modes such as \ begin {align *} ... \ end {align *} but always with errors. I am still learning, grateful for your help and all who have made further comments.

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean like this?

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,array}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\frg}{mm}
 {
  \dbn_frg:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__dbn_frg_num_tl
\tl_new:N \l__dbn_frg_den_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \dbn_frg:nn
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__dbn_frg_num_tl { #1 }
  \tl_set:Nn \l__dbn_frg_den_tl { #2 }
  \regex_replace_once:nnN { (\+|\-) } { \cT\& \1 \cT\& } \l__dbn_frg_num_tl
  \regex_replace_once:nnN { (\+|\-) } { \cT\& \1 \cT\& } \l__dbn_frg_den_tl
  \begin{array}{@{} r @{} >{{}}c<{{}} @{} l @{} }
  \l__dbn_frg_num_tl \\
  \hline
  \l__dbn_frg_den_tl
  \end{array}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\frg{4-3}{4-1}\qquad \frg{4+3}{4+11} \qquad \frg{15-2}{6+12}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, just as @marmot's answer to yours is also appropriate because you agree to increase the fraction bar thickness using \ hline [number] and also to decrease or increase the space between the denominator, bar, and numerator using \ vspace { number} or something. Now I'm looking for a way to apply a font type in a single command to the whole macro set if you have any suggestions. Thank you for your response.